# Vehicle routing optimization with certain fixed waypoint order using Google Directions or Azure Routing API?

Tags: google-directions-api, azure-maps, vehicle-routing, routific-api

Is it possible to optimize routes, but have a waypoint in a certain position using Google Maps Directions API or Azure Maps Routing API?

What I mean by this if I have the following route:

Start -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> End

I want the start and end to remain fixed where they are, but also maybe want Waypoint 1 to be in the second stop. The API should give me the most optimized route between the following two options:

(1) Start -> 2 -> 1 -> 3 -> End

(2) Start -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> End

Is it possible with the two map services?

Answer (score -1):

In Azure Maps set the `computeBestOrder` parameter of the request to `true`. Here are some related resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-best-practices-for-routing#calculate-and-optimize-a-multi-stop-route

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/getroutedirections

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Route%20Waypoint%20Optimization

Comment: `computeBestOrder` will optimize all waypoints in the best order possible. However, I am asking if I can set a waypoint to be a certain stop position and optimize around that. In my example above, I want waypoint 1 to be the second stop I make and want all other routes optimized around that (minus start and end).

Comment: The first and last waypoints in the route don't change when using `computeBestOrder`. That said, it wasn't clear what you were asking originally, if you want the second stop to stay the same (as well as start/end) you will need to calculate two routes. One from start to 1, and one that uses computeBestOrder with waypoints 1 to end. I haven't come across a service that does exactly what you are asking in a single request.

Comment: I think you are correct that there isn't a service that does this. I believe I was mistaken that Routific does this. It's probably possible as you mentioned to check certain certain waypoints from start to 1 and then the rest and use the one with the lowest amount of time or distance, but it's probably overcomplicated for my needs. `computeBestOrder` and reassigning routes without re-optimizing should work well enough for me. Thanks for the help!